# cxf Continuation

Tags: spring, cxf, jax-rs, continuations

How to get a org.apache.cxf.continuations.Continuation from a JAXRS ServiceEndpoint serviceBean or JAXWS ServiceEndpoint serviceBean.

My spring config look like that.

```
<bean id="myServiceContainer" class="cxfutils.endpoint.soap.JAXWSServiceEndpoint">
    <property name="serviceBean" ref="myReceiver" />
</bean>
```

for jaxrs it seam like you should add

```
import org.apache.cxf.continuations.ContinuationProvider;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.apache.cxf.continuations.Continuation;

@Resource
private MessageContext context;

@GET
@Path("hello")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String hello(@Context final HttpServletRequest httpRequest){
  ContinuationProvider provider = (ContinuationProvider)context.get(ContinuationProvider.class.getName());
  Continuation conti = provider.getContinuation();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the case of JAXWS the JAXWS MessageContext need to be found from WebServiceContext.getMessageContext().

you can then call context.get() on the MessageContext